# Not all GitHub Pages hosted images are loaded

Tags: github, jekyll, hosting, github-pages

I've identified really weird behaviour of GitHub pages. Server loads only single size of image and makes all others 404 even though they are there and I can see them in the repo.

I have my Jekyll source in master branch: https://github.com/Seva98/sevcik.dev/tree/master

I have built _site folder in gh-pages branch: https://github.com/Seva98/sevcik.dev/tree/gh-pages

Site with issue is: http://sevcik.dev (local version has no issues)

On top of the homepage right under `ONDREJ SEVCIK’S RESUME` in the left column should be my profile pic. There is just not loaded image error, checking console I can see some sizes were not found but if I check file manager I see that size of 800 has been loaded (only this one not others).

For example, this can't be reached https://sevcik.dev/assets/images/resized/20/selfie.jpg but this can https://sevcik.dev/assets/images/resized/800/selfie.jpg

If you check the repo both sizes are there 800 https://github.com/Seva98/sevcik.dev/blob/gh-pages/assets/images/resized/800/selfie.jpg and 20 https://github.com/Seva98/sevcik.dev/blob/gh-pages/assets/images/resized/20/selfie.jpg

Issue happens only on homepage as for example https://sevcik.dev/portfolio has exactly the same responsive images syntax and all images works.

Any idea why GH says some of those images doesn't exist even though they are there?

Should also include other sizes like /20

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is crazy but it fixed itself overnight. Looks like GitHub just needed some time to index new images.

So if you have similar issue and you are sure images are uploaded then just wait. For me it took +2 hours.